# Mysql query for identifying number of combination groups with similar data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database that I use to track enterprise systems used by school districts.  Each of the 800 school districts in my database has a list of systems in 40 different categories.  I can easily output each district's systems, or the list of districts that use each system by category.

So for example there are 121 districts that all use "Product 1" from the first category.  Of those districts, 83 use "Product 1" from the second category.  Only 32 districts also use "Product 1" from a third category, and so on.  Ultimately by spot checking the results I can find districts that have only 5 systems in common.  But I may be wrong.  There may be two districts that share 6 or 7 or even 8 systems in common.  The database is getting to large to rely upon human spot-checking!

What I am interested in is a series of SQL queries that would identify the two districts that share the largest # of systems in common.  Or better yet, a list by district, of how many systems they share in common with their associated district.

Districts A, F Share 8 systems in common.
Districts A, C, F Share 7 systems in common.
Districts A, B, C, D, E, F share 2 systems in common.

or, alternatively,

8 Systems
District A
District F

7 Systems
District A
District C
District F

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS systems;
CREATE TABLE systems( id          integer,  name    text);
  INSERT INTO systems VALUES (1,'SYS 1');
  INSERT INTO systems VALUES (2,'SYS 2');
  INSERT INTO systems VALUES (3,'SYS 3');
  INSERT INTO systems VALUES (4,'SYS 4');
  INSERT INTO systems VALUES (5,'SYS 5');
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS districts;
CREATE TABLE districts( id          integer,  name    text); 
 INSERT INTO districts VALUES (1,'DISCT A');
  INSERT INTO districts VALUES (2,'DISCT B');
  INSERT INTO districts VALUES (3,'DISCT C');
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS relations;
CREATE TABLE relations( id_district          integer,  id_system    integer); 
  INSERT INTO relations VALUES (1,1);
  INSERT INTO relations VALUES (1,2);
  INSERT INTO relations VALUES (1,5);
  INSERT INTO relations VALUES (2,2);
  INSERT INTO relations VALUES (3,1);
  INSERT INTO relations VALUES (3,3);

SELECT b.name as SYSTEMS, COUNT(*) as QTY, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) as DISTRICTS
   FROM relations a
INNER JOIN systems b
ON a.id_system=b.id
INNER JOIN districts c
ON a.id_district = c.id
   GROUP BY b.name;
```